# How to change the dot point color and style in Morris.js line graph?

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, raphael, morris.js

I uses [morris.js](http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/) to draw line chart graph, but I can't figure out how to change just dot color and style in line chart.
Does anyone know how to change just dot styles?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Use the `pointFillColors` property.
From the documentation:

> pointFillColors   Colors for the series points. By default uses the same values as lineColors

Here is the example of the chart with blue line and green dots:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="raphael-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="morris.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function drawChart() {
    Morris.Line({
        element: 'chart',
        data: [
            {y: '2012', a: 100},
            {y: '2011', a: 75},
            {y: '2010', a: 50},
            {y: '2009', a: 75},
            {y: '2008', a: 50},
            {y: '2007', a: 75},
            {y: '2006', a: 100}
        ],
        xkey: 'y',
        ykeys: ['a'],
        labels: ['Test series'],
        lineColors: ['#0b62a4'],
        pointFillColors: ['#00ff00']
    });
}

window.onload = drawChart;
</script>
<div id="chart" style="width: 400px; height: 250px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of "lineColors", try "colors"
like this:

```
function drawChart() {
Morris.Line({
    element: 'chart',
    data: [
        {y: '2012', a: 100},
        {y: '2011', a: 75},
        {y: '2010', a: 50},
        {y: '2009', a: 75},
        {y: '2008', a: 50},
        {y: '2007', a: 75},
        {y: '2006', a: 100}
    ],
    colors: ['#0b62a4','#D58665','#37619d','#fefefe','#A87D8E','#2D619C','#2D9C2F']
});
```

}

for every line there should be one color.

Comment: What if you have dynamic data that is not known for the time that colors are set?

Comment: Then you can have an array of colours and dip in to that array to pull out a colour